# Wrong result testing integer input for palindrom-ness

Tags: java, arrays, int

Java - I should save an entered number in an array and should test this wether it is a palindrom or not. My code seems to be wrong, but I don`t know why. Can you help please? Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Zahleingabe
    int input = readInt("Bitte geben Sie eine positive Zahl ein:");
    while(input < 0) {
        input = readInt("Bitte geben Sie eine positive Zahl ein:");
    }

    // Array anlegen
    int[] inputArray = new int[input];

    // Array zerlegen
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    while(input / 10 == 0) {
        j = input % 10;
        inputArray[i] = j;
        input = input / 10;
    }
    int[] newInputArray = new int[inputArray.length];
    i = 0;
    while(i < newInputArray.length-1) {
        newInputArray[i] = inputArray[i];
        i++;
    }

    // Auf Palindrom Eigenschaft überprüfen
    i = 0;
    j = newInputArray.length-1;
    while(i < j) {
        if(newInputArray[i] != newInputArray[j]) {
            write("Die Zahl " + input + " ist kein Palindrom.");
            return;
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    write("Die Zahl " + input + " ist ein Palindrom.");     

}
```

*Edit's from commments:*

- I am not allowed to convert the integer into a string and test that - I have to use an Array that holds each digit of my input and check that.
- My problem / questions: the code does not work - it tells me 122 is a palindrom which it is not, I have no clue why.
- I am not allowed to use `Math.XXX` functions (log10, pow, ...)

Comment: What do you mean by "the code seems to be wrong"? Does it fail to compile? Does it crash when you run it? Does it give the wrong answer?

Comment: It gives the wrong answer! For example, the number (input) is 122, then the answer is it is a palindrome, but it`s not.

Comment: I think the problem is to convert the number correctly into an Array!

Comment: But I can`t find an answer.

Comment: The language is Java.

Comment: your array is far too big. You create a array for 122 integers if you input 122. you need 3 digits. search for log() to correctly size your array. Also: make a string out of your number. Check if first and last character is identical. remove both. repeat until none or only one is left. decide if 12223221 is a palindrom. if 1st and last char is not euqal - no palindrom. If you need to store the number in an array, store the characters of the string as array to go around that limitation.

Comment: I am not allowed to convert it into a string.

Comment: How can I create 3 digits for my new array?

Comment: I tried it with another int h and count it up each loop, so I get the length of the array. But I can`t use h for the length because it is an int not a field.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

- get input // 121
- calculate `arrayDim = ((int)Math.log10(121))+1` // 3
- create an array of that size.
- Loop from `power=arrayDim-1` down to `power = 0`   // 2,1,0

  - calculate `powerForDivide = 10^power`   // 100, 10, 1
  - calculate `digit = inputNumber / powerForDivide` (use integer div, no decimals) // 1, 2, 1
  - put `digit` into array at `arrayDim-(power+1)` // [1,2,1]
  - reduce `inputNumber` by `powerForDivide*digit` // 121 - 100, 21-20, 1-1
- test your array

The values after **//** denote the values in the different loops for a given Input of 121.

**Code:**

```
public class JavaFiddle
{
    // get the amount of digits (==dimensions) to store an integer n
    public static int getDims(int n)
    {
        if (n < 10) return 1;

        return 1 + getDims(n/10) ; 
    } 

    // helper to calculate 10^p
    public static int tenToPower(int p)
    {
        if (p < 1) return 1;

        return 10 * tenToPower(p-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // removed console input so it works with https://javafiddle.leaningtech.com/
        int input =  12255221;

        int arrayDim = getDims(input); // ((int)Math.log10(input))+1;
        System.out.println("arrayDim(" + input + ") = " + arrayDim);

        // Array anlegen
        int[] inputArray = new int[arrayDim];

        int i = arrayDim;
        int rest = input;
        int powerForDiv = tenToPower(i-1); // (int)Math.pow(10,i-1);

        while(i > 0) {
            i = i - 1;
            // System.out.println(powerForDiv);

            int digit = rest / powerForDiv;
            int index = arrayDim - i - 1;

            System.out.println(digit + " at " + index); 

            rest = rest - digit*powerForDiv;
            inputArray[arrayDim - i - 1] = digit; 
            powerForDiv =  powerForDiv / 10;
         } 

         System.out.print("[");
         for ( int idx = 0; idx < arrayDim; idx++) { 
            System.out.print(inputArray[idx]);
            if (idx <arrayDim-1) 
                System.out.print(":");
            else
                System.out.println("]"); 
         } 

        i = 0;
        int j = inputArray.length-1;
        while(i < j) {
            if(inputArray[i] != inputArray[j]) {
                System.out.println( input + " no Palindrom.");
                return;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        }

        System.out.println( input + " is Palindrom.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, but actually I cannot youse math. functions.

Comment: That would have been an Info that you should put into the question. I added 2 helper funcs. You have to substitute them yourself.

Comment: I am sorry for this.

Comment: Cleaned up and posted solution without `Math.xxxx` - check and mark as answer if ok.

Comment: Change the part where you Input your number - my Java does not know your used fuction `readint()` - it might be `Integer.readInt(..)`